# Сеть предсказывает неверно

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, tensorflow, классификация

Я написал сверточную сеть для классификации эмоций. Обучение происходило на черно белых картинках размера 64 на 64. Всего 7 эмоций и по 1000 картинок на каждую эмоцию. Длилось обучение  10 минут. Когда я стал проверять, сеть выдает неверные ответы. Проверял и на картинках из сети и на собственных селфи с вебки

Это ссылка на картинки
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1FT-o5Cn0vAtvZoAS2T6nTa9zxI34zvbE?usp=sharing

Это ссылка на репозиторий
https://github.com/gimaevra94/emotions_detector

Чтобы повторить обучение:

1. Скачать и распаковать картинки. В коде поменять путь до картинок
2. Скачать из репозитория файл с кодом нейросети, и там еще лежит сама модель уже обученная. Для сети в коде тоже нужно указать место откуда ее загружать если вы захотите проверить обученную модель а не обучать заново

Пожалуйста подскажите что с ней может быть не так. В коде оставил пояснения чтобы легче воспринималось но если что то неясно пожалуйста задавайте вопросы. Пожалуйста помогите

Возможно кому то будет достаточно "приведенного кода":

```
#!pip install livelossplot

#!pip install PIL

import pathlib, tensorflow, livelossplot, numpy, matplotlib, PIL

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Normalization
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2DTranspose
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout

# создание каталогов под классы
#тут нкжно изменить путь на тот где у вас будут лежать картинки
path = 'C:/Users/noname1209140143/code/emotions_generator/data'

base_dir = pathlib.Path(path).parent / 'data'
train_dir = base_dir / 'train'
test_dir = base_dir / 'test'
val_dir = base_dir / 'val'

anger_dir = train_dir / 'anger'
disgust_dir = train_dir / 'disgust'
fear_dir = train_dir / 'fear'
happy_dir = train_dir / 'happy'
neutral_dir = train_dir / 'neutral'
sad_dir = train_dir / 'sad'
surprise_dir = train_dir / 'surprise'

anger_dir = test_dir / 'anger'
disgust_dir = test_dir / 'disgust'
fear_dir = test_dir / 'fear'
happy_dir = test_dir / 'happy'
neutral_dir = test_dir / 'neutral'
sad_dir = test_dir / 'sad'
surprise_dir = test_dir / 'surprise'

val = val_dir / 'validation'

# в документации написано использовать это вместо генераторов т.к. они устарели
train = tensorflow.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(directory = train_dir,
                                                    label_mode = 'int',
                                                    color_mode = 'grayscale',
                                                    image_size = (64, 64)
                                                    )

test = tensorflow.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(directory = test_dir,
                                                    label_mode = 'int',
                                                    color_mode = 'grayscale',
                                                    image_size = (64, 64)
                                                    )

# я следовал архитектуре u-net
inp = Input((64,64,1))

# вход нормализуется
norm_0 = Normalization()(inp)


# понижение размерности признакового пространсва
# свертки со страйдом вместо макспулинга
conv_0 = Conv2D(filters = 16, kernel_size = 3, padding='same', activation= 'relu')(norm_0)
conv_str_0 = Conv2D(filters =16, kernel_size = 3, strides = 2,padding='same',activation= 'relu')(conv_0)
conv_1 = Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = 3, padding='same', activation= 'relu')(conv_str_0)
conv_str_1 = Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = 3, strides = 2,padding='same',activation= 'relu')(conv_1)
conv_2 = Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = 3, padding='same', activation= 'relu')(conv_str_1)
conv_str_2 = Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = 3, strides = 2,padding='same',activation= 'relu')(conv_2)

# дилатационные свертки
dila_0 = Conv2D(filters = 64,kernel_size=3,padding='same',activation='relu',dilation_rate=6)(conv_str_2)
dila_1 = Conv2D(filters = 64,kernel_size=3,padding='same',activation='relu',dilation_rate=12)(conv_str_2)
dila_2 = Conv2D(filters = 64,kernel_size=3,padding='same',activation='relu',dilation_rate=18)(conv_str_2)

# склейка и перемешивание дилатационных сверток
concat_0 = Concatenate()([dila_0, dila_1, dila_2])
conv_1x1_0 = Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = 3, padding='same', activation= 'relu')(concat_0)

# повышение размерности признакового пространсва и проброс инфы с более ранних слоев
trans_0 = Conv2DTranspose(filters=64,kernel_size=3,strides=2,padding='same',activation='relu')(conv_1x1_0)
concat_1 = Concatenate()([conv_2, trans_0])
trans_1 = Conv2DTranspose(32, (3, 3), strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(concat_1)
concat_2 = Concatenate()([conv_1, trans_1])
trans_2 = Conv2DTranspose(16, (3, 3), strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(concat_2)
concat_3 = Concatenate()([conv_0, trans_2])

drop = Dropout(0.0001)(concat_3)
flat = Flatten()(drop)
out = Dense(7, activation = 'softmax')(flat)

model = tensorflow.keras.Model(inputs = inp, outputs = out)

model.summary()

model.compile(
    loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer = tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
    metrics = ['accuracy'])

# коллбек ловит val_loss на <=15%, останавливает сеть и сохраняет в файл
class MyCallback(tensorflow.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None): 
        val_loss = logs["val_loss"]
        if val_loss <= 0.1500:
            self.model.stop_training = True
            self.model.save('model.keras')

history = model.fit(x = train,
                    epochs = 40,
                    validation_data = test,
                    # PlotLossesKeras() рисует график после каждой эпохи
                    callbacks=[livelossplot.PlotLossesKeras(), MyCallback()]
                   )

# нужно поменять путь на тот где у вас будет лежать файл сети
model = tensorflow.keras.models.load_model('model.keras')

# нужно поменять путь на тот где у вас будет лежать тестовая картинка
filename = f"C:/Users/noname1209140143/code/emotions_generator/data/val/validation/0.jpg"
img = PIL.Image.open(filename)

# картинка делается квадратной
if img.size[0] > 64:
        left = (img.size[0] - img.size[1]) / 2
        right = img.size[0] - left
        image = img.crop((left,0,right,img.size[1])).resize((64,64))
        # поменять путь на тот где будет лежать тестовая картинка
        image.save(f"C:/Users/noname1209140143/code/emotions_generator/data/val/validation/0.jpg")
        
val = tensorflow.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(directory = val_dir,
                                                    color_mode = 'grayscale',
                                                    image_size = (64, 64)
                                                    )
pred = model.predict(val)
emotions_decoding_dict = ('anger', 'disgust', 'fear', 'happy', 'neutral', 'sad', 'surprise')
emotions_decoding_dict[numpy.argmax(pred)]

model.evaluate(train)

model.evaluate(test)
```

Comment: `left = (img.size[0] - img.size[1]) / 2` - это что-то странное, зачем вы из ширины высоту вычитаете? Вы смотрели, что у вас там в итоге то получается в тестовой картинке, а то может там бессмыслица какая-то?

Comment: ну я не придумал и не нашел ничего лучше на тот момент. по этому придумал этот костыль. этот код делает картинку квадратной не искажая то что на ней изображено

Comment: Так, папка с валидацией пустая. Где брать проверочную картинку? На трейне и тесте то скор неплохой.

Comment: И если что-то из трейна скопировать в валидацию, то определяет правильно, проверил на нескольких картинках. Так что проблема либо в неправильной подготовке картинки для валидации, либо картинка какая-то в принципе другая. Но пока вы не покажете эту картинку, я ничего конкретнее не смогу сказать.

Comment: в папку с валидацией я кидаю картинки вручную по одной. я пробовал и картинки из исходного датасета(так как не все пустил в обучение) и картинки из интернета, и селфи с вебки своего ноута. В подавляющем большинстве случаев предсказания неверные

Comment: вот именно я тоже поражаюсь. ошибка на валидации 10% но предсказания неверные

Comment: Вот и покажите - на каких **конкретных** картинках предсказания неправильные. Так то могу посоветовать добавить разные трансформации картинок в обучение. Ну там сдвиги, повороты, масштабирование, обрезка и т.д. Это типовой приём. Может помочь. А может и нет. Некоторые картинки возможно и человек не смог бы правильно соотнести, бывают неоднозначные случаи. Нужно разбираться с **конкретными** примерами.

Comment: Кстати, имеет смысл посмотреть исходные скоры до `argmax`, может там нейросеть колеблется между двумя вариантами с почти равной вероятностью. Такое тоже бывает.

Comment: я написал скрипт который отображает сразу пачку картинок с их реальными метками и предсказаниями модели

Answer (score 1):

Добавил в репозиторий файл "test" отвечающий за предсказания и конкретные картинки на которых делались предсказания. Ссылка на репозиторий: https://github.com/gimaevra94/emotions_detector

Так же привожу код из этого файла:

```
import pathlib, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, numpy as np, tensorflow as tf

                        # сюда путь до картинок
base_dir = pathlib.Path('C:/Users/noname1209140143/code/emotions_generator/data').parent / 'data'
val_dir = base_dir / 'val'

anger_dir = val_dir / 'anger'
disgust_dir = val_dir / 'disgust'
fear_dir = val_dir / 'fear'
happy_dir = val_dir / 'happy'
neutral_dir = val_dir / 'neutral'
sad_dir = val_dir / 'sad'
surprise_dir = val_dir / 'surprise'

                                    # сюда путь до модели
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('C:/Users/noname1209140143/code/emotions_generator/model.keras')

val = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(directory = val_dir,
                                                    color_mode = 'grayscale',
                                                    image_size = (64, 64),
                                                    crop_to_aspect_ratio=True
                                                    )

# тут хранятся картинки которые пойдут в предсказания
imgs=[]
# здесь метки этих картинок
labels=[]

for img, label in val:
    imgs.append(img)
    labels.append(label)

# словарь для перевода предсказаний и меток в слова
emotions_decoding_dict = ('anger', 'disgust', 'fear', 'happy', 'neutral', 'sad', 'surprise')

# перевод меток из цифр в слова
decoded_labels = [emotions_decoding_dict[label] for label in labels[0]]

# предсказания из imgs и перевод в слова
decoded_preds = [emotions_decoding_dict[np.argmax(pred)] for pred in model.predict(imgs)]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
for i in range(21):
    ax = plt.subplot(7, 7, i+1)
    fig.tight_layout()
    ax.yaxis.set_ticks([])
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks([])
    
    # здесь картинка
    plt.imshow(imgs[0][i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
    
    # здесь предсказание
    plt.title(decoded_preds[i])
    
    # здесь реальная метка
    plt.xlabel(decoded_labels[i])
    
# во время написания я ничего не перемешивал по этому это реальные предстказания. вот на столько они кривые
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]